# Starting emulator for AVD 'Android_2.2' PANIC: Could not open: Android_2.2

Tags: virtualization

How do I please to make the AVD correctly works ?

When I try to start a virtual device, I get the following message :

[image]

How do I to fix that, please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting Android Virtual machine from within eclipse or directly ?

If you are running it from eclipse then before starting eclipse just make sure to run the below command:

```
sudo export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
```

Now start the eclipse and try running AVD from it. 
I hope this helps. It solved this issue at my end when I faced the similar problem.

Comment: I'm starting it from Android studio.

Comment: That haven't worked. I'm still getting the posted error message.

Comment: Oh I see. Many times this error arises because of root issues. In my case, I installed eclipse as root but AVD was being configured for normal user. 
Well there may be several reasons for your problem.
I hope this google search can help http://bit.ly/1mG8Ris